# Merge two data frames using ID and matching string

Tags: r, if-statement, merge, stringr, grepl

Suppose I have 2 data frames:

```
df1 <- data.frame(eventId = c("6770583", "6770529"), home = c("Real Salt Lake", "Vancouver Whitecaps Fc"), away = c("New England Revolution", "Sporting Kansas City"))

df2 <- data.frame(eventId = c("6770583", "6770583", "6770529", "6770529"), currentOddType = c("New England Revolution to win 1-0, 2-0 or 2-1", "Real Salt Lake to win 1-0, 2-0 or 2-1", "Sporting Kansas City to win 1-0, 2-0 or 2-1", "Vancouver Whitecaps to win 1-0, 2-0 or 2-1"), currentOdds = c("7", "4", "4.33", "4.5"))
```

I want to merge them using eventId and team name because eventId is repeated in df2.

Desired outcome would look like this:

```
dfFinal <- data.frame(eventId = c("6770583", "6770529"), home = c("Real Salt Lake", "Vancouver Whitecaps Fc"), away = c("New England Revolution", "Sporting Kansas City"), homeOdd = c("4", "4.5"), awayOdd = c("7", "4.33"))
```

[dfFinal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2YuI.png)

Also, where there are no matches, homeOdd and awayOdd would be "NAs"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a combination of `gather`/`spread` with `left_join`

```
df1 %>%
    gather(type, team, -eventId) %>%
    left_join(
        df2 %>%
            separate(currentOddType, into = c("team", "type"), sep = "\\s(?=to win)") %>%
            select(eventId, team, currentOdds),
        by = c("eventId", "team")) %>%
    unite(val, team, currentOdds) %>%
    spread(type, val) %>%
    separate(away, into = c("away", "awayOdd"), sep = "_") %>%
    separate(home, into = c("home", "homeOdd"), sep = "_")
#  eventId                   away awayOdd                   home homeOdd
#1 6770529   Sporting Kansas City    4.33 Vancouver Whitecaps Fc      NA
#2 6770583 New England Revolution       7         Real Salt Lake       4
```

Note that `Vancouver Whitecaps Fc` becomes `NA` because the names in `df1` and `df2` are different (`Vancouver Whitecaps Fc` vs. `Vancouver Whitecaps`).